# How can I add a reference to a value-type in vala

Tags: memory-management, vala

In c++ I can add a reference to a value type, for example :

```
int a = 12;
int &b = a;

a--;
cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << endl;
```

Will give :
a = 11, b = 11

Is there a way to do the same in vala without using pointers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to do the same in vala

Yes.

> without using pointers ?

No.

If, however, you are passing them to a function, you can use a ref parameter:

```
void decrement (ref value) {
  value--;
}

void do_stuff () {
  int a = 12;
  decrement (ref a);
  assert (a == 11);
}
```